# Passing in special characters from a perl script to csh

Tags: perl, arguments, csh

I'm writing a perl script that takes a string and passes it into a .csh script.

PerlScript.pl:

```
$CMDLineArgs = "-stuff -more_stuff \'-even_more \"*stuff\" -last_stuff\'";
system(Script.csh $CMDLineArgs);
```

Script.csh:

```
set flags="$argv[*]"
```

For some reason the single quotes aren't making it into my .csh script, and the entire thing won't work if * is anywhere in the string. Any suggestions on how I can get the string exactly as it appears in the perl script into the csh script?

Comment: to start with, you should use an array with `system()` rather than a scalar string.  e.g. `@cmdlineargs=("-stuff", "-more_stuff", "'-even_more \"*stuff\"-last_stuff'"); system('script.sh', @cmdlineargs)`.   see `perldoc -f system` for details.

Comment: also, see [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C Shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt).   `csh` (and `tcsh`) is just barely adequate as an interactive shell.  it's absolutely awful and should be avoided entirely as a scripting shell.  this has useful/interesting stuff too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317247/bash-vs-csh-vs-others-which-is-better-for-application-maintenance

Comment: Unfortunately my entire companies build process is based around tcsh, so I've had to get used to it.

Comment: did you try an array rather than a string?  BTW, in case it's not obvious when passing an array to system(), each element in the perl array corresponds to one arg on the command line.  RE: csh - my condolences :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other ways to do it (I'm no expert in csh/tcsh - i disliked csh when i had to use it in the early 90s and have avoided it as much as possible ever since) but the only way I've found to do what you want in tcsh is with `set nonomatch` or `set noglob`.  For example:

perlscript.pl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

@CMDLineArgs = ('-stuff', '-more_stuff', '-even_more', '*stuff', '-last_stuff');
system('./script.tcsh', @CMDLineArgs);
```

alternatively, if you don't want to type all the single-quotes and commas, use `qw()`:

```
@CMDLineArgs = qw(-stuff -more_stuff -even_more *stuff -last_stuff);
```

script.tcsh:

```tcsh
#!/bin/tcsh

set nonomatch
set flags=($argv[*])

foreach f ($flags)
  echo $f
end
```

and the output is:

```
$ ./perlscript.pl
-stuff
-more_stuff
-even_more
*stuff
-last_stuff
```

Note how this keeps each argument as a separate element in `$flags`, instead of concatenating them all into a single string.

Comment: i just realised that `noglob` is probably better here.  With `nonomatch` if there happens to be one or more filenames that matches `*stuff` then they will be substituted.  With `noglob` then the `*stuff` is not expanded to all matching files.

Comment: i just spent 10 minutes reading and trying different things to see if there's a better way.  I now know the secret of csh.  It's not the C shell, it's the Cthulhu shell.  I just lost 1d6 SAN points.

Answer (score 2):

`Perl` provides for a variety of `quote`-ing operators for just such a scenario as you seem to be having. In particular, the `qw//`, `qq//`, and `q//` operators, standing for `quote word`, `double quote string`, and `single quote string` operators respectively. You will notice that they completely take away the drudgery out quoting data.

And as has already been pointed out, the `system()` command is better served using arguments served via a `list` rather than in `scalars` for security reasons.

Finally, inside the `cshell` code, you need to use the `:q` modifier to quote the variable.

```
%  cat PerlScript.pl
```

---

```
my @Args = (
   qw/     -stuff  /,                    # whitespace ignored
   qw/ -more_stuff /,                    # whitespace ignored
   q['-even more "*stuff" -last_stuff'], # whitespace IMPORTANT
);

my $csh_script = q[Script.csh];

system($csh_script, @Args) and
   die qq[Error: The script $csh_script has failed with exit code:], $? >> 8;
```

---

```
% cat Script.csh
```

---

```
foreach arg ( $argv[*]:q )
   echo "<$arg>"
end
```

---

## Results

```
<-stuff>
<-more_stuff>
<'-even more "*stuff" -last_stuff'>
```

---

## Notes

- If you don't think the output is to your liking, then DONOT change anything inthe csh script. Rather play with `@Args` in the PerlScript.pl file.
- For example, if you were to populate the `@Args` like as shown:

---

```
my @Args = (
   qw/     -stuff  /,
   qw/ -more_stuff /,
   q['-even more],
   q["*stuff"],
   q[-last_stuff'],
   #q['-even more "*stuff" -last_stuff'],
);
```

Then you would see the following result:

```
<-stuff>
<-more_stuff>
<'-even more>
<"*stuff">
<-last_stuff'>
```

Comment: this is a good answer but, IMO, you focused too much on the perl side (the core of which is easy - "use an array").  What's really needed is more details about csh issues, because csh is the one being difficult about passing args and globs, especially `you need to use the :q modifier to quote the variable.`, including where it's documented, and what other modifiers exist.